# htaccess 301 redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess

I want to

redirect http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=1

TO

http://www.mysite.com/

Can you please show me the 301 redirect rule for htaccess?

Thanks.

I tried the following, but no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=1$
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://www.mysite.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below configuration,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=1
RewriteRule index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

I tried it on my domain and it works fine. Hope this works for you too... :)

Comment: +1, the key point is that the RewriteRule doesn't try to match the leading slash, which won't be present when rewriting from an .htaccess file

Comment: i tried the rules abobe, the url becomes http://www.mysite.com/?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=1, it just removed the index.php not sure whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to [www.htaccessredirect.net](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/), the code to do this would be:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=1 /
```

Alternatively, you could look in to using apache's [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: sorry. it doesnt work. I dont think your rule works for url that has QUERY in it